# Non-homogenous linear systems geometry

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the linear system $$x+y+z=7; x+y-z=5; -x-y+z=3$$

How do you show that:

a) Plane 1 meets plane 2 in a line
b) Plane 1 meets plane 3 in a parallel line

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation 1 + Equation 2 : $2x + 2y = 12$ -> $x + y = 6$ this a line slope $= -1$

Equation 1 - Equation 3 : $2x + 2y = 4$ -> $x + y = 2$  this a line slope $= -1$

The two lines have the same slope so they are parallel.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :) So why do you add the equations together?

Comment: Its the same as substituting $z$ from one equation to another to find were the planes intersect.

Answer (score 0):

If You add the first two equations You get
$2x+2y=12$. So plane 1 and plane 2 intersect in the line given by the equation $y=-x+6$.
If You add the first and the third equation You get $z=5$ and inserting this in the first equation yields $x+y+5=7$ and thus the first and third plane intersect in the line given by the equation $y=-x+3$ which is obviously parallel to the other.

Answer (score 0):

For plane 1 and plane 2, you add the two equations and get $x+y=6$. Then you can obtain the parametric equation for the line assuming x as the parameter.
$$\begin{cases} x=t \\ y=6-t \\ z= 1\end{cases}$$
You can then got a picture of the line. It is in a horizontal plane with $z=1$. Calculating the tangent direction of the line, you get $(1, -1, 0)$

For plane 1 and plane 2, you can do similar work. The line equation is,
$$\begin{cases} x=t \\ y=2-t \\ z= 5\end{cases}$$
The tangent direction is $(1,-1,0)$, which is in the same direction as the first line but on different plan (i.e. $z=5$). It is thus in parallels to the first line.